# how can I increment c# variable that is used in js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
       @{ int ind = 1; }
        var words = '@Model.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ID == ind).Content';
 @{ind++;}
 </script>
</body>
```

I were expecting that it will be incremented each time I reach this block but, it compiles one time only at the same time I can't use a JavaScript variable because I'm not going to be able to pass it to first or default function

Comment: What does the above compile to (right click in browser)

Comment: it must compile each time the user press on a key but that is not the code it's just for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Razor expression like below:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ind = @ind;
        var words = '@Model.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ID == ' + ind + ').Content';
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: it brings back error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Try checking for null values like this:
var words = '@(Model.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ID == ind)?.Content ?? "")';